# Replace text with table

Tags: c#, docx, novacode-docx

I am using C# Novacode Docx library to replace string with table in a section of word file but the table is inserting below paragraph. I want to replace `text(#table1#)` with table in word file.

I have used this code but it doesn't replace on same location rather then it's inserting below paragraph:

```
foreach (var paragraph in document.Paragraphs)
{
    paragraph.FindAll("#table1#").ForEach(index => paragraph.InsertTableAfterSelf((t1)));
    document.ReplaceText("#table1#", "");
}
```

[image: see table Error in word report image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try:
**Step1**: you replace "#table1#" by one table in document.
**Step2**: in your code:
Novacode.Table t = document.Tables[0];
Novacode.Table table = t.InsertTableAfterSelf(numberRow, numberColumn);
t.Remove();